# sql server change login

Tags: sql-server

when i install the sql server i chose windows autentication mode and now i want to change it to sql server autentication plus i need it in network x( should i reinstall it again?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can just change the setting. Log into SQL Server in Management Studio, then:

- right click on the server node (the top node in the tree)
- choose "Properties"
- click on "Security"
- change the setting from "Windows Authentication mode" to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode"

I think you may need to restart the SQL Server service after making this change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your SQL Server instance to use *SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode* as currently it is configured to use *Windows Authentication* only.

Take a look at the following article for steps on how to implement the required change:

[How Do I Configure SQL Server 2005/2008 to accept SQL Authentication?](http://kbase.gfi.com/showarticle.asp?id=KBID002804)

Comment: and with this i can connect  from another computer via network?

Comment: If the servers both reside within known trusted domains then yes.